# Laravel POST request error 405: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, http

Using postman on localhost, I'm able to use POST successfully on my API. But when deployed to a server and using postman, I always get the error 405:MethodNotAllowedHttpException, even though the POST request is stated for the route, took our verifycsrf from middleware, and took out the web middleware. Also followed the CORS installation for laravel project by barryvdh.

Wondering if anyone has any suggestions to fix this?

Kernel:

```
    namespace App\Http;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

    class Kernel extends HttpKernel
    {
        /**
         * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
         *
         * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middleware = [
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors',

        ];

        /**
         * The application's route middleware groups.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middlewareGroups = [
            'web' => [
                \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            ],

            'api' => [
                'throttle:60,1',
            ],

            'admin' => [
                \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\PermissionAdminMiddleware::class,
            ],

        ];

        /**
         * The application's route middleware.
         *
         * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $routeMiddleware = [
            'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
            'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
            'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        ];
    }
```

cors.php

```
    return [
        /*
         |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
         | Laravel CORS
         |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |
         | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
         | to accept any value.
         |
         */
        'supportsCredentials' => false,
        'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
        'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
        'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
        'exposedHeaders' => [],
        'maxAge' => 5,
        'hosts' => [],
    ];
```

app.php includes         Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,

routes.php

```
       Route::group(

                [
                    'prefix' => 'api',
                    'middleware' => ['cors']
                ],

                function()
                {
                    Route::post('dummy', 'API\UsersController@dummy');

                }
    );
```

UsersController.php

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

    use App\Http\Controllers\FP\UserController;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

    class UsersController extends Controller
    {
        function dummy(Request $request){
          return "test";
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you maybe just mess up your server url, and therefore your request went to another route which does not support the post mehtod? so it happend to me...

Comment: Are you using SSL on the live server?

Comment: Post content of your POST request out of postman

Answer (score 0):

Add Accept header in postman to application/json. [image]